# how to emulate Copy menu function to reproduce a Classroom for the next term?

Tags: google-classroom

The Google Classroom class cards page provides the function / option to COPY a classroom (reproduce) for purposes such as a new term.  This COPY feature is *not exposed* in the Classroom API.
How might I emulate it?

Answer (score 0):

At the moment there is no direct way of cloning a classroom in the [Classroom API](https://developers.google.com/classroom). There is the [IssueTracker 150669916](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/150669916) which requests that feature, you could go and give it a `+1` to increase in popularity. In [#2](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/150669916#comment2) there is a workaround that could be used as an alternative, you can follow it to emulate this behaviour.

Comment: note that #2 states that you can't copy Materials via the API - which makes the suggested workaround largely useless IMJO (I imagine in most cases copying students, which is also suggested, isn't what you want to do)